# ffmpeg avfoundation (Mac OS X) capture second screen desktop

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg

I am use console ffmpeg, if I capture from first monitor, then all is well

> ./ffmpeg -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -f avfoundation -capture_cursor 1 -capture_mouse_clicks 1 -i 1:0 -c:v libx264 -qp 0 -preset ultrafast capture.mp4

if try capture from the second monitor then process hangs

> ./ffmpeg -video_size 640x480 -framerate 30 -f avfoundation -capture_cursor 1 -capture_mouse_clicks 1 -i 2:0 -c:v libx264 -qp 0 -preset ultrafast capture.mp4

My device list:

```
AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc74141a0c0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc74141a0c0] [0] HD-camera FaceTime (integrated)
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc74141a0c0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc74141a0c0] [2] Capture screen 1
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc74141a0c0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc74141a0c0] [0] Built-in Input
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fc74141a0c0] [1] Boom2Device
```

But if I replace output format from mp4 to mkv then record is well on second monitor too! How fix this bug?

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer for you but I'm trying to do a similar thing but with a duration. Do you have a solution to my question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733635/how-to-capture-a-timed-screen-recording-on-a-mac-with-ffmpeg