# Fav macos terminal app to record html content

Tags: macos, terminal, capture

To capture frames of html animations and stitch them into video,
I was about to use Timecut (available from npm).
However the result is not crisp videos - the capture is rather fuzzy for some reason.

What other terminal app would you reccomend for capturing html animations? Main goal is crisp output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you are looking for a way to record your screen with an application that can be run from the commandline.

I would use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) which is available from [brew](https://brew.sh/) more details on screen recording using ffmpeg on MacOS can be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733635/how-to-capture-a-timed-screen-recording-on-a-mac-with-ffmpeg) and on the [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop).

Remember that the resolution/"crispiness" of the video you record will be limited by your desktop resolution. Zooming in on the content you want to record might help if it's possible.